# Tab Navigation iOS

Tags: ios, tabs

Only a question, exists any library to simulate Android Navigation Tab or simulate Navigation like Spotify iOS App?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not need any libraries, you can do it by using you view controller as an container view controller with 3 child view controllers.

You may need this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/index.html

UITabeBarController may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, but I've founded a good library for that. Awesome!

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLMailBoxContainer